# class from the attached library is not activated

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, nuget

I installed the Nuget package. hooked it through the "using" . The package classes work in another solution, and in my project they do not work

screenshots:
[neolux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKyI1.jpg)

Comment: Did you create an ASP.NET Core project? When you build, what is the error?

Comment: yep. Core. 
I can not use NeoLux library classes and methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two separate issues here. I had an issue similar to @Leo in that the `TestForNet()` method is part of the `NeoDB` class.

Assuming that the method exists on the `NeoRPC` class for you, then @Leo is also spot on in suggesting that you can't create a variable (i.e. `var api = NeoRPC.TestForNet()`) within a class declaration as you have it in your screenshot.

If you'd like to set `api` when the class is created, you can create the variable at the class level and assign it in the constructor. I'm going to rely on `NeoDB` instead of `NeoRTC` in this example:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly NeoDB _api;

    public HomeController()
    {
        _api = NeoDB.ForTestNet();
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // _api.QueryRPC();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> class from the attached library is not activated

You should put the code into the **method** rather than under the **class** directly, like:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var api = NeoRPC.ForTestNet();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @a1oleg, Are you the author of this package? I have checked the source code of this package, found the method of `ForTestNet` in the class `NeoDB` rather than `NeoRPC`. Please make sure you have re-write the source code, I test download that package and using `NeoDB.ForTestNet()`, it works fine. If you are not the author of that package, I am afraid this package is not ready to use.

Comment: @a1oleg, If you are not the author of that package, and you are not re-write the source code, this issue should be related to that nuget package itself. Just as I comment before, the source code have some issue, not ready to use. If you are interesting it, you can contact the author of that nuget package.